# Linux: printing a zero-padded string of specified length

Tags: c, format-specifiers

On Linux, I am using GNU gcc 4.9.2 version and getting a strange unexpected behavior while trying to print a zero-padded string of specified length. Here's the code snippet I am trying:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
  char buff[5];
  sprintf(buff,"%04s","12");
  printf("%s\n", buff);
  return 0;
}
```

While the documentation given in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ clearly states that flag left-pads the number with zeroes (0) instead of spaces when padding is specified.
But, it's printing space padded "12" i.e. "  12" and not "0012".
remedy?

Comment: `0` padding does not work with strings. (UB)

Comment: Read the man-page **carefully** again! The behaviour is correct. And that's not related to the compiler.

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: The workaround is obvious. Think about it!

Comment: "left-pads the **number** with zeroes"

Comment: @Olaf I know what you mean, instead of using string converted to integer, what about if I want to pad with a particular character say $ so 12 will appear as $$12?

Comment: Try this sprintf(buff,"%04d",12). Padding only work for integers, not for strings.

Comment: If the string came from a number, you should just use the number directly with printf() rather than converting to a string first.

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana you need to do this by yourself, that is print $ (total_length - length_of_string) times and then printf the string with %s.

Comment: @Dr.DebasishJana: Wea re not a tutoring site. This is a basic task, even some C books use something similar as example. Being spoon-fed will not get you anywhere in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [C11 7.21.6.1p6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p6) clearly states that the behaviour of `0` in conjunction with `s` conversion specifier is undefined:

> **`0`**
>
> For `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g` and `G` conversions, leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width rather than performing space padding, except when converting an infinity or NaN. If the `0` and `-` flags both appear, the `0` flag is ignored. For `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X` conversions, if a precision is specified, the `0` flag is ignored. **For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.**

Thus the behaviour of `%04s` is *undefined* and you're *lucky* when it didn't match your expectations right away!

---

So, here's [a complete library](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/) for doing the left-pad operation most efficiently:

```
char *leftpad(char *str, size_t length, char fill, char buf[]) {
    size_t s_len = strlen(str);
    if (s_len > length) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t padding = length - s_len;
    memset(buf, fill, padding);
    strcpy(buf + padding, str);
    return buf;
}
```

This also would neatly work with *any* padding character and any padding length. Usage example:

```
int main(void) {
    char buf[65], *s;
    if (s = leftpad(buf, 64, '0', "12")) {
        puts(s);
    }
}
```

Naturally this doesn't work if the string happens to be a *negative* decimal string for example (the padding would be before the - sign).

Comment: This solution would not work if `str` had leading spaces.

Comment: @chqrlie naturally, though usually one wouldn't want to zero pad such strings anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie ok now :D

Answer (score 5):

In the [manpage of printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) you will find an exact desciption:

> `0`
>
> The value should be zero padded.  For `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversions, the converted value is padded on the  left with zeros rather than blanks. [...] For other conversions, the behavior is undefined.

So it follows that it's not defined for strings. An implementation may pad with 0 but not have to. It's undefined behaviour.

The following solution uses the `%.*s` syntax as format specifier, so there is no need of using a for loop or multiple printf calls.

```
char buff[5];
char str[] = "12";
size_t len = strlen(str);
sprintf(buff, "%.*s%s", len >= 4 ? 0 : (int)(4 - len), "0000", str);
```

---

Further you should think of using `snprintf` to prevent buffer overflows.

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.*s%s", len >= 4 ? 0 : (int)(4 - len), "0000", str);
```

The formatted output with `snprintf` may behave different with different compilers. Under Linux gcc it always appends a trailing null byte `'\0'`. The Visual Studio 2010 compiler doesn't ensure that if the string to write is bigger or equal that the buffer.

Comment: 1) Conversion of an unsigned to a signed integer is implementation defined. 2) So is conversion of a too large, which will occur if `len > 4`.

Comment: The line is a dirty hack with undefined behaviour for a longer string and not the expected behaviour for other values. The ternery operator does not change this, but makes it worse.

Comment: Simpler solution: `sprintf(buff, "%s%s",  "0000" + (len > 4 ? 4 : len), str);`

Comment: Actually it **doesn't** follow that a string is *not* padded. It is explicitly stated that the behaviour is *undefined*, so it very well can be padded.

Comment: @chqrlie: Very nice!

Comment: @Olaf: I see no problem as the tenary operator guards from any undefined or unexpected bahaviour. For any string greater or equal 4 a 0 will be used otherwise the calculation is possible and between 1 and 4. Where is the problem?

Comment: "I see no problem as the tenary operator guards from any undefined or unexpected bahaviour." - 1) It leaves implementation defined behaviour and can result in a trap representation. 2) It changes the behaviour (asssuming the common 2's complement conversion). "For any string greater or equal 4 a 0" - No.

Comment: @Olaf indeed, what implementation-defined behaviour there is left the code as it is written now?

Comment: `4 - (size_t)len` where `(size_t)len < 4` can be converted into any standard integer type without implementation-defined behaviour. But the UB from a string longer than the buffer still remains...

Comment: @Antii: Yes agree but I wrote he should use `snprintf`.

Comment: @Olaf: I agree with Antii and don't see the problem, please try one more explanation.

Comment: @Olaf: do you advocate to use `(4 - (int)len)` instead of `(int)(4 - len)` if `len <= 4` ?